# How get info into variables from command output

Tags: linux, nginx, grep

I am run `nginx -V` and get like this:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built by gcc 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-5J5hor/nginx-1.18.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-compat --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

From this result I am need to 2 variables

1. version of nginx: "nginx-1.18.0"
2. start from "--with-cc-opt" and to the end of line

How get this info? I am try for getting version

```
nginx -V | grep -E -o 'nginx-[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}'
```

but it not work

Answer (score 3):

`nginx -V` sends output to stderr instead of stdout, so you may need to redirect its output to stdout first.

```sh
$ nginx -V 2>&1
```

Then you can `grep` what you need from `nginx -V`.

```sh
$ nginx -V  2>&1 | grep -E "^nginx"
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0

$ nginx -V  2>&1 | grep -E "^(nginx|configure)"
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 ... --with-mail_ssl_module
```

Comment: Thanks you! It's work for me. I am don't know about stderr and stdout